# ¿cual es el equivalente de lblconteo.Text = Len(txtMensaje.Text); en c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

tengo este metodo para contar la cantidad de caracteres digitado y esta en Visual Basic

```
lblconteo.Text = Len(txtMensaje.Text);
```

como lo haría en c# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza la propiedad [`.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) que te da la cantidad de caracteres en un `String`:

```
lblconteo.Text = txtMensaje.Text.Length.ToString();
```

Nota que tienes que utilizar `ToString()` ya que la propiedad `.Length` es de tipo `Int32` y `lblconteo.Text` acepta `String`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int conteo = txtMensaje.Text.Length;
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la cantidad de caracteres mediante la propiedad **[Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx)** y puedes convertir este valor a String para usarlo en tu label:

```
lblconteo.Text = txtMensaje.Text.Length.ToString();
```

O también como otra opción:

```
lblconteo.Text = Convert.Tostring(txtMensaje.Text.Length);
```